# How to create a 4 variables chart in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have been trying to figure out a way to create a chart with 4 variables in Excel. I can get to 3 with no problem but the 4th variable seems not possible.

Here is my data (I am working with decoding libraries):

- Rotation/Inclination Angle of the camera
- Type of Barcode
- Library used for decoding
- Decoding speed (either actual speed or the time to decode)

Basically I would have something like:

```
0' - QR Code - Lib#1 - 100ms  
0' - Aztec - Lib#1 - 0ms [NOT DECODED]

0' - QR Code - Lib#2 - 20ms  
0' - Aztec - Lib#2 - 10ms

5' - QR Code - Lib#1 - 250ms  
5' - Aztec - Lib#1 - 0ms [NOT DECODED]

5' - QR Code - Lib#2 - 40ms  
5' - Aztec - Lib#2 - 100ms
```

and so on...

I have 9 Libraries, 4 types of barcode, 12 inclination/rotation and the data related to them.

Comment: This is very hard to understand... You've not explained what your data is, just a description of the data. When you say chart, do you mean as in a graph, or just in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Excel you can chart 4 variables on a single chart, but the results will likely be difficult to interpret.  Generally, you'll chart your data on an XY/Scatter Chart, using your two quantitative values Rotation/Inclination and Decoding Speed on your X and Y axis (if none of your values were quantitative, you could use the X and/or Y axis as categories).  Then, breaking your data into series based upon all four values, you'll encode your qualitative data Barcode and Library as shape and color.  You could add another category and encode it as size, but comprehension of the results would be nearly impossible IMHO.

Here's a sample of what it could look like:

[image: 4d scatter]

Based upon the data you described, you'll have 36 series (4 bar codes x 9 libraries) plotted on 12 points along the X axis.

As an alternative, consider a Panel Chart (small multiples) where the XY axis remain the same, but there is a separate chart for each pair of Library and Barcode.  That would look something like this:

[image: 4dPanel]

For more info on this type of solution, also check this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/757980/graph-in-excel-to-represent-correlation-of-3-parameters/757985#757985).